# for loop iteration to create new columns in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to substring some columns, not all. For example, if I have a dataset:

```
` data <- data.frame(A = c(100, 200, 300), 
               B = c('A50', 'B60', 'C70')
               c = c(900, 800, 700))
```

I would like to substring columns A and B, but not C.

```
  select_col <- c("A", "B")

 for col in select_col {
   newcolA = substr(colA, 1, 3)
   newcolB = substr(colB, 1, 3)
  }
```

How to write the for loop properly? My actual dataset have hundreds of columns, and I have more than 20 columns to substring.

Comment: Is your `substr` consistent? Like is it always going to be `substr(…,1,3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` on a vector of columns (or `lapply`):

```
sapply(data[,select_col], substring, 1, 3)

     A     B    
[1,] "100" "A50"
[2,] "200" "B60"
[3,] "300" "C70"
```

To change column and store it in same dataframe:

```
cbind(data, setNames(lapply(data[,select_col], substring, 1, 3), paste0("new", select_col)))
    A    B   c newA newB
1 100 A501 900  100  A50
2 200 B602 800  200  B60
3 300  C70 700  300  C70
```

Comment: Thanks! How could the results of sapply be saved as extra columns? In specific, I would like to have "newA", "newB" append to "data".

Comment: `colnames` function can help you with that

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit more intuitive to new R users:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(100, 200, 300), 
                   B = c('A50', 'B60', 'C70'),
                   c = c(900, 800, 700))

select_col <- c("A", "B")

for(a in select_col) {
  data[[paste0("newcol", a)]] <- substr(data[[a]], 1, 3)
}
```

I'm assuming you want to put it into the same data frame. If so, that should work. Otherwise, you could create a new data frame with the same number of rows:

```
newdata <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 0))
```

and then change `data` in the loop to `newdata`. If you actually want a separate vector for each one (as your code suggests), you could use `assign`, but I'm guessing you don't.